# Two TextViews behind each other, ellipsize only the first, second one always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, ellipsis

I have two TextViews arranged in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Because they are display only a couple of words, the first one is limited to `maxLines=1` and `ellipsize=marquee`.

Normally, it would look like this:

**Text in TextView1** *Text in TextView 2*

However, if TextView 1 gets too long, TextView 2 will no longer be visible, due to the first one taking up all the space:

**Text in TextView1 text text text text...**

Now, I'd like to ellipsize TextView 1 only, so that TextView2 is always fully visible. I've tried setting `layout_weight="1"` to the first one, but that leaves space when not ellipsed.

**Text in TextView1** -------------------*Text in TextView 2*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does it have to be a `LinearLayout`?
If not:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:text="This is a very very long string that eventually will get out of screen; yes, it is that long!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textview2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textview2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:text="Hello! I'm short!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This still leaves space though, when TextView 1 is not long enough

Comment: you're right; check my updated answer, it should work now.

Comment: Strange thing is that it doesn't work if you replace gravity from "left" to "start". And also it doesn't work for me on Nexus S with Android 4.1.2 (everything is aligned to the right, as there is no gravity=left)

Comment: But it works when I replaced "left" with "fill_horizontal", very strange. Investigation would be good :)